# MongoDB playground output not showing in VS Code terminal

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a few queries on MongoDB playground extension. According to the documentation, the output of the queries should be shown in a terminal. However, A new file is opening up to display the result and the playground output tab of the terminal is empty.

How do I get it to show the result in the terminal?

[image]

Comment: I also have this problem, but for me it just shows nothing.

Comment: @Andrei I also face that problem. For me, opening playground in c: drive instead of d: drive solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use **print()** or **console.log()** command

> Note that print and console.log will print in the VS Code Output
> panel, while **the result of the playground is displayed in an editor**.

See https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/print-function-in-vscode-extension-is-missing/103118/2

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help whoever looking for the solution.

Go to View , select "open View.." and type "playground output".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENez9.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).